# How to programmatically add CheckBox Column to RadGridView control. Error Message: A Column with the same Name exists in the collection

Tags: datagridview, radgridview, datagridviewcolumn, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I'm trying to add a CheckBox Column to RadGridView control using code.

Below is my code:

```
Sub AddCheckColumnGrid()

    '  Dim chkSelection As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn // Microsoft Control
    Dim chkSelection As New GridViewCheckBoxColumn '// Telerik Control
    With chkSelection
        .HeaderText = "Check"
        .Name = "Check"
        .Width = 80
    End With

    gvDisplay.Columns.Insert(0, chkSelection)
End Sub
```

The form with the GridView is displayed as a DialogBox using the code below

> .ShowDialog()

**My Challenge:**
When I open the form for the first time, it works fine.
When I try opening it again, I get the error message

> A Column with the same Name exists in the collection.

**What I have done so far:**

1) I tried the code with the

> Visual Studio Default DataGridView and DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn. [Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJ8Lj.png)

The Microsoft DataGridView doesn't give error but anytime I open the form, a new Check Column is added to the grid. If I open it 10 times, 10 check columns will be added. That is not what I want. No matter how many times I open it, I want just one column added to the grid. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaRko.png)

2) I added:

> gvDisplay.Columns.Clear()

I got that suggestion from [Refreshing RadGridView with Programtically added Button : A column with the same Name already exists in the collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23071318/refreshing-radgridview-with-programtically-added-button-a-column-with-the-same)

Unfortunately, I didn't make me happy :(
When I open the form, only the "Check" Column shows. All the Columns from the Database don't. [Check Display here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQHTo.png)

3) I'v read few links to the Telerik Documentation but I'm still not getting it.

How do I fix the error message?:

> A Column with the same Name exists in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

The code below did the trick for me.

I put the Insertion in IF Condition

```
If NOT gvDisplay.Columns.Contains("check") Then
gvDisplay.Columns.Insert(0, chkSelection)
End If
```